# nodejs - unable to connect to an ibmi db2 instance using sequelize 7

Tags: node.js, electron, db2, sequelize.js, db2-400

I've successfully installed sequelize 7 in my electron app. I need to connect to a db2 database that will run on an ibm i system AS400 but I'm having some trouble to connect with the database. I've used the following code

```js
        const sequelize = new Sequelize('mydb', 'myuser', 'mypwd', {
            host: '192.168.0.15',
            // one of our supported dialects:
            // 'mysql', 'mariadb', 'postgres', 'mssql', 'sqlite', 'snowflake', 'db2' or 'ibmi'
            dialectModule: require('odbc'),
            dialect: 'ibmi' ,
            //dialectOptions: {
            //    odbcConnectionString: 'CMT=1;NAM=0;DATABASE=Iasp01;HOSTNAME=192.168.0.15;UID=myuser;PWD=mypwd;PORT=446'
            //}
        })

        console.log(sequelize)

        try {
            sequelize.authenticate()
                .then( () => {
                    console.log('Connection ok')
                }).catch( (e) => {  
                    //event.sender.send('databaseUpdateCompleted', JSON.stringify(e) )
                    console.log( util.inspect(e, { showHidden: true, depth: true, colors: true }) ) 
                    //console.dir( e )
                })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
```

In the console, when I log the error that is returned from sequelize, I will get this messages, but I'm unable to expand the objects into the error

```js
  [message]: '[odbc] Error connecting to the database',
  [cause]: [Error: [odbc] Error connecting to the database] {
    [stack]: 'Error: [odbc] Error connecting to the database',
    [message]: '[odbc] Error connecting to the database',
    odbcErrors: [Array]
  },
  name: 'SequelizeConnectionRefusedError',
  [parent]: [Getter],
  [original]: [Getter]
```

Looking into the sequelize object, I've found that the used port is set by default to 25000 but we don't have this port configured. Can be this cause of the issue, how I can connect with the db2 using node odbc and sequalize?? If I try to connect using MS Access or other tools like dbeaver, all wil work fine. I suspect that the proxy we use in our company will block the connection?